# How to index a cell array class property in Octave?

Tags: octave

I have a cell array class property:

```
classdef imageSet
    properties (SetAccess='protected', GetAccess='public')
        ImageLocation = {''}; % Image locations
    end
...
```

and I would like to access it with indexing like this:

```
imgSet.ImageLocation{3}
```

But I get an error message: *can't perform indexing operation on array of imageSet objects*

However

```
a = imgSet.ImageLocation
a{3}
```

works fine. Why, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score -1):

You must have an array of `imageSet` objects. You can check this with

```
size(imgSet)    % Will be something other than [1, 1] (a scalar)
```

The reason that `a = imgSet.ImageLocation` works is that `imgSet.ImageLocation` creates a comma separated list and *only the first `imgSet` object is assigned to `a`*. This first object is then a scalar `imageSet` object and you can therefore index into the `ImageLocation` property without issues.

This can be demonstrated the following way

```
% Create an array of structs
a = struct('one', {1, 2, 3}, 'two', {4, 5, 6})

% Create a comma-separated list from the one field
b = a.one;

% See that only the element was used (a(1).one)
disp(b)
%   1
```

Since it is an array, you'll need to access a *specific* `imgSet` object prior to indexing

```
imgSet(1).ImageLocation{3};
```

Comment: Actually size(imgSet) is [1 1].

Comment: @Balint Please provide code to reproduce the entire issue then. The error clearly states that you have an array. I'm not sure why it would think any other way. Regardless, doing `imgSet(1).ImageLocation{3}` should work.

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere else. If you have matlab: this is the imageSet.m.
`a = imageSet('path/to/images/folder');
a.ImageLocation{3} % works fine
b = select(a,1:4);
b.ImageLocation{3} % can't perform indexing operation on array of imageSet objects`

Here is the relevant part of the code: [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e3eee45fa0c2703a9590d93d2941c464)